# html canvas-color and images

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm trying to make a menubar type of thing for my website.
I tried google but idk what I should search on...
I want it to be a kind of rainbow and when the user hovers over it the bar should expand and it should give a short description of the page they will be going to.
I did it with  and javascript:

```
    <canvas id="purple" width="50" height="400"></canvas>
```

js:

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById('purple');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(0, 0, 100, 500);
    context.fillStyle = 'purple';
    context.fill();
    context.lineWidth = 0;
    context.strokeStyle = 'none';
    context.stroke();
```

and that with all 6 colors.
No problem so far for me.
But now I want to put in the text... But I keep failing.
This is my JSFiddle:

> http://jsfiddle.net/gY9wk/
>   should I keep using  or something else?

O and another question: Can I remove the white spaces between the bars?
This is less important than the first question but just asking...

Thanks in advance!
Robin van der Noord.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using canvas for something like that might be a little bit too expensive.

There are two ways to create text on them - using canvas to draw text or using another HTML element on top of each canvas and put the text in it. I recommend the latter. Here is an example using a div container and a span inside it (as a canvas sibling) to show the text: http://jsfiddle.net/gY9wk/9/ (added a few effects to make it look nicer)

The new structure is this:

```
<div class="item">
    <canvas id="red" width="50" height="400"></canvas>
    <span>Hey there</span>
    <p>This is a description</p>
</div>
```

Again, I'd recommend not to use canvases for backgrounds as they are too heavy. A simple 1px-high horizontal line with `repeat-y` property would do the trick and would look identical. And I especially don't recommend using canvas to render text, not just for the reasons mentioned above, but for SEO as well (web crawlers won't see the canvas-rendered text).

Of course, if you plan to create some animations, then the canvas is the way to go.

---

And here's an example how to render text on canvas (see the purple one) if you still want to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/gY9wk/10/.

Bear in mind that CSS resizing will stretch whatever is rendered on canvas, and changing the width or height attributes of the canvas element will clear the canvas and you'd need to rerender whatever was on it.

```
    context.fillStyle = 'red';
    context.font = "16px Arial";
    context.lineWidth = 4;
    context.fillText("Hey, I'm rendered on canvas", 30, 30);
```

---

Second question, the white space is coming from canvases being displayed inline by default. The easiest way is to set them to:

```
canvas {display: block;}
```

and to remove the line break elements (`br`s).

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/gY9wk/5/

Comment: That really helped me!!
Thank you so much
And the SEO isn't that important for this issue..
But thanks for the tip I'll keep it in mind!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad I helped you. It never hurts to have a good SEO, but again, the main reason I'm against the canvas in this case is because it can all be done using pure HTML/CSS and bg images. Cheers! :)

Comment: You said I could use css but can you change the size of the color bars with css?

Comment: Yup, the can try making the black gradient on the left via CSS or bg image, and then just set the bar color to the color you need. See the green one here: http://jsfiddle.net/gY9wk/11/ Basically, it just needs that black gradient as a background image (and of course, you can adjust the color using HEX/RGB values instead of "green").

Comment: That is actually better than canvas because you can just hover over the text without the bar acting weird and stuffs!
Thanks I'll try it!